# So I'm Having Significant Trouble With Extracting Data from Nested Arrays. I've Tried Everything

Tags: javascript, html, arrays, nested, javascript-objects

So in retrospect I kind of regret doing the JavaScript this way, but nonetheless I have tons of JSON data that I need to pull from so I can format this webpage through for loops and JavaScript-created elements.

To be exact, I've created buttons from the top layer of the JSON data ('Pancakes','Eggs'), now I'm trying to extract the 'item' and 'price' when those JavaScript-created buttons are clicked on, and after that I'm going for 'add-ons'.

So the question lies mainly in the openSubCat() function. How would I interact with a deeper layer of the 'data' and create further buttons? What am I doing wrong?

A little bit of what I've been working on :

JSON data-

```
const data = {
    "Breakfast":[
            {



        "Pancakes":[
        {"item":"1 Pancake",
        "price":2.00,

            "add-ons":{"blueberries":{
                "add-on price":0.50},
            "chocolate chips":{
                "add-on price":0.50},
            "M&Ms":{
                "add-on price":0.50},
            "Strawberry Topping":{
                "add-on price":0.50}
                }
            },
        {"item":"2 Pancakes",
        "price":3.00,
        
            "add-ons":{"blueberries":{
                "add-on price":0.50},
            "chocolate chips":{
                "add-on price":0.50},
            "M&Ms":{
                "add-on price":0.50},
            "Strawberry Topping":{
                "add-on price":0.50}
                }
            } ,  
        {"item":"3 Pancakes",
        "price":4.00,
                
            "add-ons":{"blueberries":{
                "add-on price":0.50},
            "chocolate chips":{
                "add-on price":0.50},
            "M&Ms":{
                "add-on price":0.50},
            "Strawberry Topping":{
                "add-on price":0.50}
                }
            }, 
            
        {"item":"4 Pancakes",
        "price":5.00,
                        
            "add-ons":{"blueberries":{
                "add-on price":0.50},
            "chocolate chips":{
                "add-on price":0.50},
            "M&Ms":{
                "add-on price":0.50},
            "Strawberry Topping":{
                "add-on price":0.50}
                    }
                }  
            ],
            
        "Eggs":[
            {
                "item":"1 Egg Any Style w/Toast & Homefries",
                "price":2.50
            },
            {
                "item":"1 Egg Any Style w/Toast, Homefries w/ Sausage Patty or Ham",
                "price":5.00
            },
            {
                "item":"2 Eggs Any Style w/Toast & Homefries",
                "price":3.00
            },
            {
                "item":"2 Eggs Any Style w/Toast, Homefries w/ Sausage Patty or Ham",
                "price":5.00
            }
        
        ]
    ]
}
```

openBreakfast() is activated by an onclick attribute on the HTML page-

```
var s = false;

function openBreakfast() {
    console.log(data.Breakfast);

    initiateBreakfast();
    if (j==false){
        menuStart.style.display = 'block';
    j = true;
    document.getElementById("lunchbtn").style.top = "215%";
    document.getElementById("breakfast").innerHTML ="Breakfast ▴";
    menuStart.style.left = "0%";
    
    } else{
        menuStart.style.display = 'none';
    j=false
        document.getElementById("lunchbtn").style.top = "100%";
        document.getElementById("breakfast").innerHTML ="Breakfast ▾";
        menuStart.style.left = "0%";
        
    }
}
```

initiateBreakfast() successfully created buttons out of the contents of "Breakfast"-

```
   function initiateBreakfast() {
        
        if (i==15) {
            console.log(i);
            return;
           
        }else{

        data.Breakfast.forEach(item => {
            // it's an object, so lets get its first key
            itemName = Object.keys(item)[i];

            btn = document.createElement("BUTTON");
            btn.setAttribute("onclick", "openSubCat(this.id);");
            btn.textContent = itemName + "▾";
            btn.value = itemName;
            btn.id = itemName;
            btn.className = "opener";
            //btn.addEventListener("click", openSubCat());
            
           
            

            menuStart.appendChild(btn);

            btn.style.transitionDuration =".5s";
            btn.style.position = "relative";
            btn.style.fontSize ="16px";
            btn.style.color = 'black';
            btn.style.width = '80%';
            btn.style.left = '10%';
            btn.style.padding = '15px 15px';
            btn.style.borderRadius = '15px';
            btn.style.cursor = 'pointer';
            btn.style.display = 'block';
            
            

            i++;
            initiateBreakfast();
          })}
    }
```

What I've been working on most recently to get the id of the clicked "Breakfast" button and use it to determine what the next group of created buttons will be-

```
function openSubCat(opener) {
    console.log(opener);
    console.log(data['Breakfast'][opener][u]);
    var helper = data.Breakfast;

    menuStart.style.transitionDuration = ".5s";
    menuStart.style.left = "-100%";

    if (s == false) {
    var div2 = document.createElement("div");
    div2.id = "itemsmsmsms";
    div2.style.top = "87.5%";
    div2.style.width = "100%";
    div2.style.height = "auto";
    div2.style.position = "absolute";
    
    } else {

    document.body.appendChild(div2);
    if (u==15) {
        console.log(u);
        return;
       
    }else{

    data['Breakfast'][opener][u].forEach(item => {
        // it's an object, so lets get its first key
        itemName = Object.keys(item)[u];

        btn2 = document.createElement("BUTTON");
        btn2.setAttribute("onclick", "openFormModal(this.id);");
        btn2.textContent = itemName + "▾";
        btn2.value = itemName;
        btn2.id = itemName;
        btn2.className = "itemmm";
        //btn.addEventListener("click", openSubCat());
        
       
        

        div2.appendChild(btn2);

        btn2.style.transitionDuration =".5s";
        btn2.style.position = "relative";
        btn2.style.fontSize ="16px";
        btn2.style.color = 'black';
        btn2.style.width = '80%';
        btn2.style.left = '10%';
        btn2.style.padding = '15px 15px';
        btn2.style.borderRadius = '15px';
        btn2.style.cursor = 'pointer';
        btn2.style.display = 'block';
        
        

        u++;
        s=true;
        openSubCat();
    })}}}
```

**Thank you for any help**

/

Comment: Please read the usage description of the `json` tag, especially what is in capitals. What you have is a JavaScript object literal. The term JSON should better be reserved for the text format of data.

Comment: Just changed to 'javascript objects'

Comment: I would even remove the term "JSON" from the text of your question. If I read correctly, you describe what you have done, and what you are currently doing. I don't see a clear problem statement, nor a question.